# Azure API App Service not accessible with VIP but Working with URL

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps, azure-virtual-network

I have a API App With is accessible with URL. But VIP of same API is not working?
How can i Fix this?

I have checked same URL with `NSLOOKUP` Its showing same IP.

Comment: @whoever down-voted : If you can explain why then it might help me some how.

Answer (score 0):

Azure App service Architecture is not based on the IP as like Azure Cloud Service. There is not way to Access the Azure APP via IP.

you can configure internal, External, Static IP for the APP but its for App's internal use only.